# Media Resource Control Protocol (MRCP) Client and Server implementation in python

Tags: sip-server, python-sip, avaya, unimrcp

I want to integrate ASR (Open AI whisper) and TTS server with close IVR system such as Avaya. I was recommend to build this server using MRCP protocol. May need your help from where to start and is there any tutorials or documentation which can help me to create this server. I have google a lot but could not find any good literature. Please help

Comment: Have the same question, following as well

Comment: Hello Ivan, I have come across unimrcp. Maybe you can take a look too. But still unable to figure out how to implement

Comment: Yes, I am looking on that one too, I think unimrcp is using C++ , is that right?

Comment: Hi, I managed to install UniMRCP on my own and my sip call is already connected to UniMRCP, but still have no idea how to modify UniMRCP so it can connected to our own TTS

Comment: Hello Ivan, I Am also trying to figure out the plugin part. I will let you know if can find any solution. There is MRCP client implemented in python but for server side there is no code. There is also some plugins maybe you can refer that. Let’s me know if you get any success